# How can I synchronize JavaScript objects between Greasemonkey scripts on different computers?

Tags: greasemonkey

Is it possible to synchronize JavaScript objects between Greasemonkey scripts? I have created a website blocks script that stores a list of websites to block, as well as a list of websites to allow, but I don't yet know whether Greasemonkey has any methods for synchronizing these variables between different instances of the same script on multiple computers.

Is it possible to synchronize the data that is saved using `GM_setValue` on multiple computers?

Comment: It may also be possible to do this in Tampermonkey, the Google Chrome version of Greasemonkey. The relevant discussion can be found here: http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synchronize `GM_setValue`s by [synchronizing your Firefox preferences](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you). `GM_setValue` data is stored in the preferences.

For javascript objects, JSON encode them and store them with `GM_setValue`.

Other than that, you would have to set up a web application, of your own, that would receive, store, and transmit JSON-encoded data.  Your script would send and receive using `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`.